# Help with Schengen visa and possible other visas for Indian Citizen (from US) travel

Tags: visas, schengen

Indian Citizen travelling from US to EU. Will be landing in Sweden, then making my way through UK, France, Belgium, Netherlands, Germany, Switzerland, Italy, Austria and other countries.

My itinerary is from Gothenburg (Sweden) > London (UK) > Paris (France) > Brussels (Belgium), Amsterdam (Netherlands), Vienna (Austria), Venice, Rome, Vatican City, Pisa, Florence (Italy), Lucerne, Interlaken, Geneva (Switzerland).

My question is:

1. I am making my trip across europe, with my first entry point at Sweden. Can I apply for Schengen visa from Swedish embassy?
2. Apart from UK Visa and Schengen visa, do I need any other visas?

PS: I am an Indian citizen based out of US.

Answer (score 2):

All of the places you mentioned with the exception of the Vatican and the UK are Schengen members.  Based upon what you wrote, you would apply once to Sweden and your Schengen, if successful will cover all the member states.

The Vatican is not a Schengen signatory, but is a *de facto* member without border controls in the first instance.  It means any visa allowing you into Italy will work for the Vatican.

The UK is not a Schengen signatory and requires Indian nationals who intend to visit to have an **entry clearance** (a visa issued by a post outside of the UK) prior to arrival.

In summary, two applications.

Comment: Also note that the Schengen visa would need to be multi-entry, since they'll leave the Schengen zone when entering the UK, then need to re-enter it later in the trip

Comment: @Gagravarr The Schengen visa should be a two-entry visa (they are specifically intended to allow a side-trip to the UK), not a multiple-entry visa.